# Load external sites div into iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, load

I a have department site aimed at a specific audience. I am looking to add a list of related links of an external site at the end of each article.

The list of links will be in a div, ex: `<div id="linktoc"><a href="external.com">link 1</a>, <a href="external2.com">link 2</a>, etc...</div>`

The iframe would be below the div

Now the goal is to load the div `<div class="article">HTML Content I want</div>` from the external links above into the iframe.

I have limited jquery knowledge and basic html knowledge. I doubt this makes much difference but will be loaded into a Content Editor Web Part in Sharepoint 2007.

Thank you to any of you that are able to help.

Comment: As far as I know you can't really load an element from a url into an iFrame, unless it's on your own domain and you're using load() to load that element into another page that you show in the iFrame, or you can parse the HTML on the serverside extracting the element, but in either case an iFrame would'nt really be needed!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) - the browser won't allow you to manipulate a Web page that belongs to another domain.

It could work if the "external" sites belonged to the same domain:

- your page: http://team.company.com/myPath/mySite/myPage.aspx
- "external" link: http://team.company.com/otherPath/otherSite/otherPage.aspx

Comment: Maybe I have some misgivings on domain/subdomain, but my site is team.company.com and the other company.company.com. I assume this would not make it any more possible. I was aware of the same origin policy but I obviously did not completely understand what it limits.  Thank you both for your explanations.

Comment: Correct, team.company.com and company.company.com are considered different domains. You'll need to look into more sophisticated techniques like postmessaging as workarounds, or get the content through other channels - or just display the whole page in the iframe. JSONP or CORS are two other cross-domain techniques, but SharePoint doesn't support them.

Comment: Last time I drag this out, but if I choose to load the whole page, I could use jquery to hide elements (ex: display:none) where it doesn't equal the class im looking for, correct?

Comment: Same issue, you can't because the loaded page is in a different domain.